# Java lossy XOR between chars

Tags: java, types, char, xor

I'm not sure how XORing is supposed to be "properly" done between chars in Java. I've seen others do this, but when I have something as simple as:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char c = (char) a ^ b;
```

I get a "possible lossy conversion from int to char" compile error. I'm not sure how ints are being brought into this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `^` on a `char`, the operation is done in the `char`'s int value.

Because of [operator precedence](http://operator-precedence.com/java), the casting comes before the `^`.

This means that it compiles to

```
((char) a) ^ b
```

Since the casting comes first, the promotion to an `int` happens last, and you will be trying to assign an `int` to a `char`

You want to use parenthesis:

```
char c = (char) (a ^ b);
```

Comment: Nice one, I initially overlooked that subtle detail :-)

Comment: Thanks! Now it actually compiles!

Answer (score 2):

The caret (xor) operator works on int values. You char variables and b are implicitly promoted to type int to make that possible. That part works without loss of precision.

But then your code forces the int value back into the char type. You can simply make c of type int to fix this, or by correct usage of parenthesis.

Comment: OK, thanks! Is there a way to actually xor chars then, since I am trying to XOR some input for encryption purposes

Comment: Don't work on chars. Convert them to bytes, and keep in mind encoding!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how ints are being brought into this context.

In your example the XOR of two chars  could *potentially* overlap the range of the char type, so the compiler produces an int for this statement.
While here that is not the case since `97^98` is `3` but like the `a` and `b` variables are not `final`, these can be changed later and so the compiler doesn't accept to assign the result to a `char`.
Use constant values or inline them and you don't need any cast :

```
final char a = 'a';
final char b = 'b';
char c =  a ^ b;
```

Otherwise narrow the result of the XOR operation to a char only if you are sure that this will not create any side effect :

```
char c =  (char) (a ^ b);
```